# Combinations of array values using google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is my JS code

```js
var allArrays = new Array(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'z'], ['d', 'e', 'f']);

function getPermutation(array, prefix) {
 
    prefix = prefix || ''; 
    if (!array.length) { 
        return prefix; 
    } 

    var result = array[0].reduce(function (result, value) { 
        return result.concat(getPermutation(array.slice(1), prefix + value)); 
    }, []); 

    return result;
}

console.log(getPermutation(allArrays));
```

Now when I convert the same to Google Appscript it doesnt seem to work at all. What am i missing?

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because it doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 1):

For a start console.log() doesn't work in GScript, replace it with Logger.log().

Putting it into a GScript it seems to work fine:

```
function test_getPermutation() {

  var allArrays = new Array(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'z'], ['d', 'e', 'f']);

  function getPermutation(array, prefix) {

      prefix = prefix || ''; 
      if (!array.length) { 
          return prefix; 
      } 

      var result = array[0].reduce(function (result, value) { 
          return result.concat(getPermutation(array.slice(1), prefix + value)); 
      }, []); 

      return result;
  }

  Logger.log(getPermutation(allArrays)); // [16-10-12 10:27:36:400 BST] [acd, ace, acf, azd, aze, azf, bcd, bce, bcf, bzd, bze, bzf]

}
```